# Recaching page and web service under high load

Tags: c#, web-services, caching

I have a web shop with two layers of cache. One the web service and one in my web project. The problem is that when I want to recache, because of price changes or adding new products, the site crashes and a request limit is reached.

In the web service, I have taken out all the cache entries from `HttpRuntimeCache` and rerun all methods in it. (I have triple checked that they were all successful.)

While they run I still keep the original cache and the new ones become `_temp_cachekey` and when all are complete I overwrite the old data like so:

```
foreach (string key in Cache)
{
    var value = HttpRuntime.Cache[key];
    if (value != null)
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(
            key.Replace("_temp_", ""), value, null,
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null
        );
    }
}
```

After this i kill all cachekeys on the site like this:

```
List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();
foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry cacheItem in HttpRuntime.Cache)
{
    toRemove.Add(cacheItem.Key.ToString());
}
foreach (string key in toRemove)
{
    if (!key.Contains("MyPagesIndex"))
    {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I can overcome this issue? Am I missing something? Is there a better way to rebuild a runtime cache?

note: if my site have visitors<100 then it works fine and if above, the server cpu is still at maximum 10-20%

Comment: Using the enumerator on HttpRuntime.Cache is apparently very costly that might explain the crash.

Comment: I've heard so aswell but i still don't think that's the problem @StefanE . because i tried breaking up the two killcaches and kill the web service cache first and then 3 minutes later using ´System.Timer´ i kill the sitescache! but it still crashing when there's about 180 users online

Comment: Could you try look in the event logs and see if you can find the error when it does crash? Could maybe give something more to work on

Comment: Actually in the catch block i send an email to myself like this : 
`Date/Time: 2017-08-01 06:53:52 Adress: GetAllArticles?apiKey=***&IndexID=1291 Error message: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. `
Indicating that i probably get a db timeout or deadlock, which i shouldn't because all db querys and other heavy methods are cached. But even if i missed one or two the web service should still be able to survive. with just those two uncached